# svn log revision without last commit

Tags: svn

I retrieve svn log information with next command

```
    svn log --xml svn://srv-vrn/sendinfo -r {2013-03-04}:{2013-03-05}
```

but it always returns the last commit information, even the date of last commit less then start date at the revision(-r) parameter. In my case it returns:

```
<date>2013-03-03T12:59:29.916222Z</date>
```

How to make it show commits only from date range?

Answer (score 0):

You have to read SVN Book, ["Revision Dates"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates) part and understand paragraph "Is Subversion a Day Early?"

> If you specify a single date as a revision without specifying a time of day (for example 2006-11-27), you may think that Subversion should give you the last revision that took place on the 27th of November. Instead, you'll get back a revision from the 26th, or even earlier.

If you **have** revisions at 2013-03-04 and want to include in log, you have to use time 23:59 in start-parameter.

BTW, I haven't idea, how to get first revision from day for log, if you have more than one revision in this date